# How can I act on cursor activity originating from mouse clicks and not keyboard actions?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to do something when a user moves the cursor to another location via a mouse click, but not do it when it's done via a keyboard action (arrows, pageup/pagedown, home/end).

- I can't just listen to `cursorActivity` since it triggers on both keyboard and mouse actions.
- I'm not sure I can listen to `mousedown`, because it might be the start of something which is not a cursor location change (e.g. selecting, dragging).

What's the best way to catch those mouse-originated cursor movements?

Comment: `a user moves the cursor to another location via a mouse click` Can you explain this part?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova If it's not clear from the tags: it's a question asking about the [CodeMirror editor](https://codemirror.net/). By "another location" I mean the user changing the current cursor location by mouse-clicking some text in the editor.

Comment: Can you post your current setup for the codemirror editor?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I'm not sure what you mean by "setup", and in any case - does it matter? I saw no configuration options that controls anything like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could listen to these events:

- mousedown
- cursorActivity
- keydown
- beforeChange

The cursor was moved by a mouse click if these conditions are met:

- A `cursorActivity` event is triggered after a `mousedown` event
- No movement key was pressed between the two events
- No change was made to the content between the two events
- No text is selected

```js
var movedByMouse = false;

var editor = CodeMirror(document.body);

editor.on("mousedown", function () {
    movedByMouse = true;
});

editor.on("cursorActivity", function () {
    if (movedByMouse) {
        movedByMouse = false;
        if (!editor.getSelection()) {
            console.log("Moved by mouse");
        }
    }
});

editor.on("keydown", function () {
    if (isMovementKey(event.which)) {
        movedByMouse = false;
    }
});

editor.on("beforeChange", function () {
    movedByMouse = false;
});

function isMovementKey(keyCode) {
    return 33 <= keyCode && keyCode <= 40;
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `cursorActivity` is triggered when a keyboard key is pressed. Your `keyUpHandler` sets `movedByMouse` to true when a person types anything in the editor.

Comment: I updated the code snippet to account for cursor movements triggered by changes made to the content (for example, when typing text).

Comment: Could you listen to _all_ cursorActivity events, get the current cursor position and filter only those events that originate after an `onmouseup` where the cursor hasn't changed position?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works well, except that it triggers on every cursor change when selecting text by dragging.

Comment: @tmslnz - According to my tests, the `mouseup` event is not triggered in CodeMirror.

Comment: I made the correction for the cursor change when selecting text by dragging the mouse. As a bonus: it simplified the code. However, the initial mouse click of a text selection is detected as a cursor change.

Comment: Yea, detecting the start of a selection is a shame, but I'm not sure how to approach it either. In any case, this is a simple solution that works better than just listening to mousedown (doesn't trigger on drags, doesn't trigger when the cursor doesn't change), so thanks!

Comment: I added a condition in `cursorActivity` to check if some text is selected. It accounts for text selection resulting from double-clicks (mentioned by adeneo in a comment to his own answer).

Answer (score 4):

All Mouse Events (that I know of):

- onclick
- oncontextmenu
- ondbclick
- onmousedown
- onmouseenter
- onmouseleave
- onmousemove
- onmouseover
- onmouseout
- onmouseup

So, basically, there's no solution for your problem that's in javascript AFAIK. However, you can go with your second suggestion and track events and depending on them to choose whether to execute your action or not.

```js
var editorElement = document.body;
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(editorElement);
var mouseEvents = [
  'click',
  'contextmenu',
  'dbclick',
  'mousedown',
  'mouseenter',
  'mouseleave',
  'mousemove',
  'mouseover',
  'mouseout',
  'mouseup'
];
var mouseEventsLog = [];
var lastCursorPosition = null;
var doAction = function() {
  var previousEvent = mouseEventsLog[mouseEventsLog.length - 2];
  var lastEvent = mouseEventsLog[mouseEventsLog.length - 1];

  if (((previousEvent === 'mousedown' && lastEvent === 'mouseup') || lastEvent === 'click') &&codeMirror.getSelection().length <= 0) {
    if (codeMirror.getCursor() !== lastCursorPosition) {
      console.log('Cursor changed by clicking.');
    }
  }

  lastCursorPosition = codeMirror.getCursor();
};
for (var i = 0; i < mouseEvents.length; i++) {
  editorElement.addEventListener(mouseEvents[i], function(event) {
    mouseEventsLog.push(event.type);
    if (event.type == 'mouseup') {
      doAction();
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

*Note: I tried combining `cursorActivity` and mouse events, but `cursorActivity` is executed before them? I'm actually not sure what happens there =D*

Comment: Thank you for the solution! On the surface it works well, though that condition in doAction() doesn't seem very robust. For instance, if a user moved the mouse a little between the mousedown and mouseup event - but not enough to initiate a selection - it will fail to trigger. Also, the `codeMirror.getSelection().length <= 0` bit means that if there's a selected area and then a user clicks outside of that area, that click won't be counted.

Answer (score 4):

You can hook into CodeMirror by using a hook, and define your own event that fires when the cursor changes from a mouse click on the editor

```
CodeMirror.defineInitHook(function (editor) {
    editor.cursorDidChange = false;
    $(editor.getWrapperElement()).on({
        mousedown : function() {
            if (editor.cursorDidChange) CodeMirror.signal(editor, 'cursorClick');
        },
        mouseup : function() {
            editor.cursorDidChange = false;
        }
    });
    editor.on('cursorActivity', function(e) {
        if (e.isSelection) editor.cursorDidChange = true;
    });
    editor.on('beforeSelectionChange', function(e, range) {
        var start = range.ranges[0].anchor, end = range.ranges[0].head;
        e.isSelection = range.origin == '*mouse' && start.line == end.line && start.ch == end.ch;
    })
});
```

This uses a flag and a timer to catch both events if they happen within a short time of each other, as the click handler fires right after the cursorActivity handler.

Here's a working example of how to use the newly defined event with CodeMirror :

```js
/* Create Hook */
CodeMirror.defineInitHook(function (editor) {
 editor.cursorDidChange = false;
 $(editor.getWrapperElement()).on({
     mousedown : function() {
            if (editor.cursorDidChange) CodeMirror.signal(editor, 'cursorClick');
        },
        mouseup : function() {
            editor.cursorDidChange = false;
        }
    });
    editor.on('cursorActivity', function(e) {
     if (e.isSelection) editor.cursorDidChange = true;
    });
    editor.on('beforeSelectionChange', function(e, range) {
        var start = range.ranges[0].anchor, end = range.ranges[0].head;
        e.isSelection = range.origin == '*mouse' && start.line == end.line && start.ch == end.ch;
    })
});
/* -------------- */
/* Create an editor to test it */

var $this = $('.code').eq(0),
    $code = $this.html(),
    $unescaped = $('<div/>').html($code).text();
        
$this.empty();
    
var editor = CodeMirror($this.get(0), {
    value       : $unescaped,
    mode        : 'javascript',
    lineNumbers : true,
    readOnly    : false
});

/* Lets test out the new event */
editor.on('cursorClick', function() {
 $('<div />', {text : 'Cursor moved when clicked !'}).appendTo('#result')
        .show(1).delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
});
```

```css
body {background: #eee;}
.code {margin: 10px 0;}
#result {color: green;}
.CodeMirror {height: auto!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- EDITOR -->
<div class="code">test.fn = test.prototype = {
    display : function() {}
        console.log("Move cursor by clicking");
        console.log("Move cursor with keys");
    },
 pushStack: function( elems ) {
  // This is just pseudocode to have something to test
 }
    return false;
}</div>
<!-- EDITOR END -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Looks great and very neat approach with defining a new event. It seems to fail to trigger, though, when the time between the mousedown and mouseup is over 300ms, since mousedown is the one causing the cursor change and mouseup is triggering the onclick. Also, your solution will consider double- or triple-clicking to select as 2 or 3 separate cursorClick events, even if all the clicks are done at the end of the span so the cursor doesn't technically change location.

Comment: @Oak - Then I guess I'll have to change the approach a little, dropping the timer, and instead checking for selections etc. See if that solves anything.

Comment: Better! Unfortunately it now also triggers when starting a selection, though to be honest it is, technically, a cursor location change.

Comment: Yes, if you click somewhere else to start a selection, it would trigger, as the cursor moves. If you start a selection from where the cursor is currently at, it shouldn't trigger. I don't think there's any way to distinguish between just moving the cursor and moving the cursor to start a selection, other than checking if a selection was made after the fact, and that would cause a significant delay in the logic.

Comment: A shame, but I can't see a way to make that distinction either :-( I like this solution, though I ended up accepting the answer with a simpler solution. Thanks a lot anyway! By the way, your solution doesn't catch cases where you select some text and then click inside the selection - I'm not sure why.

Comment: No problem, that answer does pretty much what I started out with, just with globals and more handlers, so it sure works, it even fires multiple times when you doubleclick etc.